# Magento observer works on localhost and not on the server

Tags: php, magento

I made an observer for category creation and it works fine in localhost (on Mac) and doesn't work fine on the server (Linux).

config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Vmo_CategoryToAttributeOption>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Vmo_CategoryToAttributeOption>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <vmo_categorytoattributeoption>
                <class>Vmo_CategoryToAttributeOption_Model</class>
            </vmo_categorytoattributeoption>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <vmo_categorytoattributeoption>
                <class>Vmo_CategoryToAttributeOption_Helper</class>
            </vmo_categorytoattributeoption>
        </helpers>
        <events>
            <catalog_category_prepare_save>
                <observers>
                    <vmo_categorytoattributeoption_model_observer>
                        <class>vmo_categorytoattributeoption_model_observer</class>
                        <method>savecategoryobserver</method>
                    </vmo_categorytoattributeoption_model_observer>
                </observers>
            </catalog_category_prepare_save>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

and this is local/Vmo/CategoryToAttributeOption/Model/Observer.php

```
class Vmo_CategoryToAttributeOption_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer
{
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function savecategoryobserver($observer)
    {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $cat_model = $event -> getCategory();

        $name = $cat_model->getName();
        Mage::log("works: " . $name);
    }
}
```

and this is Vmo_CategoryToAttributeOption.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Vaimo_CategoryToAttributeOption>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Vaimo_CategoryToAttributeOption>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Do you have any idea what is wrong? Because on localhost it works great, but on the live server it doesn't.

Comment: if it works on your local, so I think there is no problem with your code. Have you tried to refresh the cache ?

Comment: yes I did. Also I did the reindexing and it still doesn't work. it just stuck when I try to create category - it only shows please wait and loading

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My money is on the fact that your local machine is on Windows/MAC and the server is linux.
on Windows/MAC the file names are case insensitive and on linux they are case sensitive.
You declared the class in your event like this:

```
<class>vmo_categorytoattributeoption_model_observer</class>
```

This means Magento looks for the class in the file `vmo/categorytoattributeoption/model/observer.php`. On windows/MAC it finds it, on linux it does not exist.
To solve it declare the model like this:

```
<class>Vmo_CategoryToAttributeOption_Model_Observer</class>
```

Or better yet, in the standard way

```
<class>vmo_categorytoattributeoption/observer</class>
```

Comment: that is the right answer! Thanks! my local machine is Mac - ignoring case :)

Comment: @user2331875 woa, I didn't know that Mac is ignoring case sensitive ? I must be something else

Comment: @user2331875. Ok...sorry for my ignorance. I forgot about MAC. I will update the answer.